# Using Grid with File Fields to get thumbnail

Tags: ee2, file-uploads, grid

I'm using the new Grid system in EE 2.7.3 and trying to create an image gallery with it. Typically I'd use the normal file upload format as a normal file:

```
{image}
    <img src="{path}_thumbs/{filename}.{extension}" alt="{title}">
{/image}
```

But with the grid system I have to use

```
{gallery_images}
     <img src="{gallery_images:community_image}" alt="{gallery_images:title}">
{/gallery_images}
```

How can I get that to go to the path for the thumbnails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your original code if you prefix variables with the Grid field's short name. The purpose of the prefix is to avoid conflicts with the outer Channel Entries loop; it doesn't affect functionality.

```
{gallery_images}
     {gallery_images:community_image}
          <img src="{path}_thumbs/{filename}.{extension}" alt="{title}">
     {/gallery_images:community_image}
{/gallery_images}
```

Comment: This does not work in EE 2.9.0. Have you tested this in other versions?

Comment: It is broken in EE 2.9.0. Replacing `/system/expressionengine/libraries/Grid_parser.php` with an old version fixed the problem.